# Best practice for lazy loading Python modules

Tags: python, coding-style

Occasionally I want lazy module loading in Python. Usually because I want to keep runtime requirements or start-up times low and splitting the code into sub-modules would be cumbersome. A typical use case and my currently preferred implementation is this:

```
jinja2 = None

class Handler(...):
    ...
    def render_with_jinja2(self, values, template_name):
        global jinja2
        if not jinja2:
            import jinja2
        env = jinja2.Environment(...)
        ...
```

I wonder: is there a canonical/better way to implement lazy module loading?

Comment: Another reason to lazy load might be because it's a poorly written third party module that depends on global environment settings that need to be changed before importing. (These modules are much fun, of course.)

Comment: FWIW, lazy import functionality is [drafted in a PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0690/) and in [discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-690-lazy-imports) as of Aug 2022.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There's no reason for you to keep track of imports manually -- the VM maintains a list of modules that have already been imported, and any subsequent attempts to import that module result in a quick dict lookup in sys.modules and nothing else.

The difference between your code and

```
def render_with_jinja2(self, values, template_name):
    import jinja2
    env = jinja2.Environment(...)
```

is zero -- when we hit that code, if `jinja2` hasn't been imported, it is imported then. If it already has been, execution continues on.

Comment: Sometimes more words is detail, but sometimes more words is just more words.  :)

Comment: Never Benchmarked it, but I seem to remember that import wasn't THAT fast.

Comment: @Glenn -- too much coffee, can't stop typing!

Comment: Also an obvious difference is, that you code pulls the jinja2 only in the local scope - or do I miss something here?

Comment: @mdorseif -- there are two different issues. (1) yes, the jinja2 name  is only visible inside that function's scope, but (2) the jinja2 module remains cached in sys.modules, so additional imports (on subsequent calls to that function or anywhere else) are effectively no-ops. I assume that you were planning on putting that 'global jinja2; if not jinja2:' code in multiple functions?

Comment: @bgporter: occasionaly. I probably used have a dozen lazy import approaches over the years and started wondering what the best way to do it is. There seems to be some consensus my example (module = None) is "bad practice" but little reasoning. I think the 'glancing at the module header' is something which shouldn't be lost. Perhaps a 'from __buildins__ import None as jinja2' approach? But looks horrible, too.

Comment: @mdorseif: the reason `jinja2 = None` is bad is because it is so unusual.  When I see that line, I don't think, "He's going to import it later, jinja2 is a module".  It looks like you are initializing a global variable to None.  The only reason I have any inkling to your intent is because "jinja2" is a well-known module name in the community.  If I saw `chemical3 = None`, I'd have no idea what you are doing.   Import the module locally in functions, it's the best way.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) If you want a way for glancers to know what is going on, then put a comment at the top like, "# I use jinja2 throughout this code, but import it locally to avoid long startup times."

Comment: ...Unless...  you are writing code for Apache Airflow..., but that's due to the way Airflow works, it fires up a new Python interpreter for (more or less) every scan it does of the DAGs. See their website if this applies to you.

Answer (score 30):

```
class Handler(...):
    ...
    def render_with_jinja2(self, values, template_name):
        import jinja2
        env = jinja2.Environment(...)
        ...
```

There's no need to cache the imported module; Python does that already.

Comment: Hmm. I think I heard that putting modules into the local scope is not considered best practice - although I'm not sure why.

Comment: @mdorself It's better practice that what you had rocking.

Comment: @aaronasterling care to elaborate?

Comment: The drawback is that you can't just look at the top of a py file and see what modules it uses, but you could put a comment if you think it's necessary. This is certainly better/cleaner than what the OP was doing, however

Comment: The Unladen Swallow talk at PyCon pointed out that for subpackage imports (which is different to this case) there's a reasonable amount of work done parsing and looking up the import levels in sys.modules so don't assume imports are cheap in a frequently-called function (he got a 20% performance improvement optimizing a django function that did this)

Answer (score 12):

The other answers have covered the actual details but if you *are* interested in a lazy loading library, check out [apipkg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/apipkg) which is part of the `py` package (`py.test` fame).

Comment: It allows you to load only once, globally (rather than in each of the 27 places where the first call to ``jinja2`` _might_ happen), and have the actual loading be performed automatically when (and only when) the first access is attempted. Nice Python magic. (Don't try this in C++.)

Comment: Oh, this is amazing. It doesn't even try to load until you access some *attribute* on the lazy loaded thing. So even doing `from mypkg import path` (from the example) doesn't import anything until I try to access something on `path`.

Answer (score 4):

Nice pattern from sqlalchemy: dependency injection:

```
@util.dependencies("sqlalchemy.orm.query")
def merge_result(query, *args):
    #...
    query.Query(...)
```

Instead of declaring all "import" statements at the top of the module, it will only import a module when it's actually needed by a function.
This can resolve circular dependency problems.

Comment: I think this what I want... is the util decorator defined directly in sqlalchemy?  Is there nothing that does this outside of sqlalchemy?

Comment: even though this tool is part of sqlalchemy, it does no database-related stuff. You're quite free to use it. As for me, I'd prefer local imports, i.e. within the function's body