# Importing package only when main is run in python package

Tags: python, import, package, program-entry-point

I like to test my packages in python using the following code at the bottom of my package:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

where `main()` is a function I define above. Now my question is this:

I need to import extra packages in my main for testing my module that are NOT necessary to import if a user is just importing my module (ie. from another script). Is there a way to only import these extra packages if my main is explicitly run? And when my package is just imported (ie. from another script), these extra packages are NOT imported.

Comment: What is the intent of not importing the packages?

Comment: Possibly main is the only function that calls functions in the imported module (and import takes a while for these modules somehow)

Comment: you can always import the modules in your specific function

Comment: just import the packages in your main() function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not put your import statements directly in the body of your `main()`? That should do it.

```
def main():
   import my_module # import ONLY if main is called
   # code
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you python for making sense :)

Answer (score 3):

In Python, you can place imports at any point in the code.

So you could have:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import <package> # place your imports here
    sys.exit(main())
```

"Lazy imports" are discussed in detail in  in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177735/best-practice-for-lazy-loading-python-modules)