# logging to stdout and to file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I want some of my loggings to be printed to the terminal and some others exclusively printed to a file.

```
import logging as log

filelog = log.getLogger ('file')
filelog.addHandler ( log.FileHandler ('example.log') )
filelog.setLevel (log.DEBUG)
log.getLogger().setLevel (log.DEBUG)

log.debug ('print to terminal')
filelog.debug ('print to file')
```

This prints both lines to the terminal (and also the second one to example.log). But I wanted only the first line to be printed to the terminal.

Strangely, when I comment out the `log.debug` line the `filelog.debug` line does not print to the terminal anymore but only to the file.

A possible solution would be initialize two separate loggers like

```
stdlog = log.getLogger ('stdout')
filelog = log.getLogger ('file')
filelog.addHandler ( log.FileHandler ('example.log') )
```

but that's pretty annoying if you're using modules and have to import both loggers.

Comment: The example configuration doesn't ever configure the logging system's root logger, so it ends up using a "last effort" handler and all bets are off, really. What would specify which messages are destined for a file and which should be shown on the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [lazy loading of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177735/best-practice-for-lazy-loading-python-modules) in Python, in order to be done using one line of import (`instead of import logging; logging.getlogger(name)`).

For completeness the project structure:

```
.
├── main.py
├── myprogram.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mylogger.py
```

Code, main.py:

```
# just import your logger module
from utils import mylogger
# do not import anything here, that wants to use 'your logger', as it is not modified yet!

def setup_logging():
    mylogger.MyLogger.logName = 'myProgram'
    mylogger.MyLogger.logLevel = 'DEBUG'
    # Overwrite the module variable
    mylogger.log = mylogger.MyLogger().get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # logging has to be setup first
    setup_logging()

    # Now you can import everything that wants to use your logger!
    import myprogram
    # your actual program is started here
    # in all modules imported afterwards you can just do: 
    #       from utils.mylogger import log
    #       log.debug(...)
    myprogram.main()
```

Code, mylogger.py:

```
# utils/myLogger.py
import logging
import sys

class MyLogger:
    logFile = '/tmp/myProgram.log'
    logLevel = 'DEBUG'
    logName = 'myProgam'

    def get(self):
        fh = logging.FileHandler(MyLogger.logFile)

        logging.basicConfig(
            level=getattr(logging, MyLogger.logLevel),
            format=
            '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d - %(levelname)s: [%(threadName)s] %(message)s',
            datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
            handlers=[fh, logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)]
        )
        # 2 handlers (file and stdout), can be more!

        log = logging.getLogger()
        return log


# log has to be overwritten from main.py
log = None
```

Code, myprogram.py:

```
from utils.mylogger import log

def main():
    log.debug('foo')
```

Call and Output:

```
python main.py
>>> 2023-03-07T00:20:30.243 - DEBUG: [MainThread] foo
cat /tmp/myprogram.log
>>> 2023-03-07T00:15:40.717 - DEBUG: [MainThread] foo
```

Explanation:

- You have a module variable `log` within `mylogger.py` which defaults to `None`.
- In `main.py` you just import `mylogger.py` at module level, then setup/modify your own logger using `setup_logging()` and overwrite `mylogger.log`
- In `main.py` import your actual program in `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.
- All others imports (and following ones) done in `myprogram.py` are using the modified/overwritten logger from `mylogger.log`

Comment: This would be _very_ unorthodox use of `logging`. The idea is that your various modules/etc. can instantiate loggers for themselves, not that you have a central location with one blessed logger.