# How can I make add type annotations to this Python code that dynamically assigns attributes to a class?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I have the following Python code that dynamically imports a module and sets an attribute on a class dynamically:

```py
class _ModuleRegistry(object):
    _modules = {}

    def defer_import(
        self,
        import_statement: str,
        import_name: str,
    ):
        self._modules[import_name] = import_statement
        setattr(self, import_name, None)

    def __getattribute__(self, __name: str):
        if (
            __name
            and not __name.startswith("__")
            and __name not in ("defer_import", "_modules")
        ):
            import_statement = self._modules.get(__name)
            if import_statement:
                exec(import_statement, locals())
                setattr(self, __name, locals().get(__name))
            ret_val = locals().get(__name)
            if ret_val:
                return ret_val
            else:
                return None
        else:
            val = super().__getattribute__(__name)
            return val


registry = _ModuleRegistry()

registry.defer_import("from pandas import read_csv", "read_csv")

print(registry.read_csv)  # I want this to have function type hinting
```

I want the type checker to be able to infer the function type of the `read_csv` function.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Code that's truly **dynamic** is inherently incompatible with a **static** type checker. If the modules you import can only be determined at runtime, then it's not possible for a type checker to infer the types.

If your usage is not really dynamic, and you just want it to defer imports to when the functions are called, then you could list out all the potential imports in a typing stubs `.pyi` file, or in a `TYPE_CHECKING` block.

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    # Here I'm using `defaultdict` as an example, because mypy-play doesn't have typing
    # information for `pandas`.  But it should work the same.
    from collections import defaultdict
    from argparse import Namespace
    registry = Namespace()  # just an arbitrary object that supports attribute assignment
    registry.defaultdict = defaultdict
else:
    class _ModuleRegistry:
        ...
    registry = _ModuleRegistry()

registry.defer_import("fromfrom collections import defaultdict", "defaultdict")

reveal_type(registry.defaultdict)
# Revealed type is "Overload(def [_KT, _VT] () -> collections.defaultdict[_KT`1, _VT`2], ...
```

(also see [mypy-play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=41390e34445a188c256ce641b146a95b))

But I would still recommend against doing this, since it's an unusual pattern and also pretty verbose. This really feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If the goal is deferred imports, then you could achieve the same with [inline imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177780/4909228), i.e. put the import statement in function bodies, directly above the call site. There's also Python interpreters with lazy import mechanisms, such as [Cinder](https://github.com/facebookincubator/cinder), but that would be a much bigger change.

Comment: "*If the modules you import cannot be determined at runtime [...]*": You mean type checking time?

Comment: @InSync Hah, yes, I meant to say "can only be determined at runtime". Edited. Thanks for catching this!